# Does offloading files to faster servers ruin site performance?

Tags: networking, cdn, network-speed

With a decent server and HTML on it, will offloading the CSS/JS/Images to another, faster server ruin the performance? I was thinking about sending, say

> www.domain.net => main, decent server
>
> cdn.domain.net => faster server

and have my code include, say

```
 <link href="//cdn.domain.net/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

But my question is, will it make the loading slower due to multiple connections or will it help speed it up due to faster download speeds?

Comment: @downvoter tell me why you down voted this question. It's useless to down vote if they cannot get any improvements out of it.

Comment: The two biggest problems with the question are: 1. It's dependent on the exact details of your website and not enough of those details were supplied (and they *couldn't be* within the character limit here).  2. This is a web application design problem, not a sysadmin problem.  Although many sysadmins might know the answer, if you were giving this problem to one of your teams in a large organisation to solve, it would not be the sysadmin team.  It's also worth mentioning that the quickest and most accurate way to get the answer is to *benchmark it yourself*.

Comment: @Ladadadada  1. How is it dependent? The question is "will multiple connections ruin the performance." 2. It is about networking, hence connections.

Comment: The number and size of the static files, the geographical locations of your site, the user and the CDN, the speed difference between the main server and the CDN and even the performance of elements outside your control such as the user's DNS resolver.  Any one of these could make an answer wrong.  Asking a yes/no question is not well suited to StackExchange either.  There are only two possible answers and one of them is wrong.  That said, nearly every significant site *does* put static files on a separate domain/server/CDN so it's probably a good idea for you too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has advantages to serve a single CSS file from the same server because your CSS probably references several images. The access to the main server is usually faster because the client has to do a DNS lookup for the CDN host. CSS files are static, can be compressed well and are usually not big anyway. Give the web server a precompressed version of the file so that it can be sent without any delay.

Comment: If I were to use an IP to bypass DNS lookups, would it make as much of a difference?

Comment: @rtainc That does not work with all domains but I assume it will with CDN servers. Use a tool like Firebug or Chrome's network analyzer to see how much time that saves. Using your main server also saves the connection establishing time. That does not matter much when loading big images but the CSS data should be available with minimum latency.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will definitely do some testing with the speeds. I have access to a DreamHost VPS so I was thinking I'd offload every file but HTML to it.

Comment: @rtainc But consider that you risk broken URLs if the CDN operator decides to change the IP addresses someday. That risk is probably not worth the performance gain. If you do that you should check in short intervals whether the IP address changes.

Comment: I didn't think about that; thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your premise of `cdn.domain.net` being a "faster server", then no, performance will not be ruined.  Generally speaking, performance should be improved.

For example, on this very site (view source now) CSS and JS files are hosted by `cdn.sstatic.net`.  Although it's undoubtedly a proper CDN, it's the equivalence to offloading those assets to a single server with tremendous bandwidth and resiliency.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just wish I would know why they down voted so I could improve.